# Instancing a class with different constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor

Assuming that I have an class named `class1` and a class `class2` that extends it. I want to understand what would the next line mean when it comes to instancing a class object

`class1 classObjectName = new class2();`

I know that I am using the constructor of `class2` but my question is how does this line affects method usage if I will use methods from either of classes

Also

`class1 classObjectName = new class1();`

`class1 classObjectName = new class2();`

My question is how many instances have been created after these 2 lines and is it from class1 or class2?

Thank you

Comment: Just a nitpick: Java naming conventions have classes begin with an upper case letter (Class1).

Comment: If you instance ClassChild and assign it to a variable of ClassParent, it makes the resulting variable of type ClassParent. This means any methods declared in ClassChild will not be usable since the compiler sees it as type ClassParent.

Comment: So if I get it correctly, I have instantiated 2 objects `class1` and `class2` right ? `class1` is a type of `class1` and `class2` of a type `class`

Answer (score 0):

I put together a example which shows some of the behavior. When assigned as the Parent, the Child instance loses access to it's Child specific methods and data but retains the data. This means if you cast it back to the Child it will be usable as the Child again.

Main:

```
public class Main
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ClassParent parent = new ClassChild("Child");
    
    parent.ChildMethod(); //Compiler Error
    System.out.println("Value: " + parent.childValue); //Compiler Error

    //Still an instance of ClassChild even if seen as a ClassParent by the compiler
    System.out.println("Child Instance: " + (parent instanceof ClassChild)); //true
    
    ClassChild child = (ClassChild) parent;
    
    child.ChildMethod(); //No Error
    System.out.println("Value: " + child.childValue); //Retains child variable data
  }
}
```

Parent:

```
public class ClassParent
{
   
}
```

Child:

```
public class ClassChild extends ClassParent
{
  public String childValue;
  
  public ClassChild(String value)
  {
    childValue = value;
  }
  
  public void ChildMethod()
  {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you really for elaborating. for my other question and I will take from the example you made.`ClassParent parent = new ClassChild("Child");` in that line , is the instance from ClassChild or ClassParent ?

Comment: @AmrMahmoud It remains an instance of ClassChild but is seen by the compiler as a ClassParent. This is why it throws errors when trying to access ClassChild methods/data but still retains that data, allowing it to be casted back to a ClassChild. This is also why you can use the [instanceof](https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator) operator to identify it as actually the ClassChild.

Comment: @AmrMahmoud I added a line in the Main method to show what I mean by using `instanceof` to confirm it's still an instance of the ClassChild.

Comment: Thank you really for the help . Much appreciated man